# Django: custom widgets in custom modelchoicefield

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using a custom Modelchoicefield class in order to get the full names of a part of the users group rather than their usernames:

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s" % (obj.get_full_name())
```

In the form, I then call this class before defining widgets for the other fields in "class Meta":

```
tutor = UserModelChoiceField(User.objects.filter(groups__name='teachers'))
```

Is there a way to add a widget to the "tutor"-field? I would like to add "class='form-control'" to the HTML output.

Thanks,
Tobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will do:

```
tutor = UserModelChoiceField(
    User.objects.filter(groups__name='teachers')
    widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
```

Although if you're gonna use bootstrap in more places, you should consider crispy-forms or similar library.

Comment: Thanks - could have thought of that myself, but somehow my mind was blocked. This solution does work (adding a comma between the lines though).